# How to redirect to a URL after logging in with Firebase using AngularFire and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularfire

Upon the User logging in, I'd like the webpage to redirect. I've attempted two different ways to accomplish this:

- Add a line right after '$scope.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('google',AuthHandler)()' that redirects the url
- Add an AuthHandler that redirect to a different page upon being logged in if successful

Although, the login works, the redirect doesn't work for an unknown reason.

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <p>Welcome, {{user.google.displayName}}</p>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" id="Gbtn" ng-click="GoogleLogin()">
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x"></i>
    Login with Google</button>  
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function AuthHandler(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    window.location.href = "explore.html";
  }
} 

var app = angular.module("app", ["firebase"]);

  app.service("Ref", ["https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/", Firebase]);

  app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", "Ref", function($firebaseAuth, Ref) {
    return $firebaseAuth(Ref);
  }]);

  app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope","Auth", function($scope,Auth) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;

    $scope.GoogleLogin = function () {   
      $scope.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('google',AuthHandler)()
      window.location.href = "explore.html";
    };

  }]);

  app.run(["$rootScope", "Auth", function($rootScope, Auth) {
    $rootScope.user = Auth.$getAuth();
  }]);
```

Also, see here for my codepen: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/YPGeYx?editors=101

Comment: This is covered in the docs under [Using Authentication with Routers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes) and there is also an [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) which implements these concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manually redirect in this case. Using $state.go('state where to go')
And states can be defined using $stateProvider.

Check the below 2 tutorials for basics of $stateProvider

1. http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/
2. http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-2/

Comment: just to confirm, is this the only option?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer. Please mark it as completed, otherwise, notify me. Thanks